# Batch select on multiple columns in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

How can I do a batch select on multiple columns in DB2, so:

```
Select * from randomTable where (col1, col2) in ((1,3),(2,4))
```

The above query works in HSQLDB.
Note that

```
Select * from randomTable where col1 in (1,2) and col2 in (3,4)
```

is not correct, because (1,2) and (3,4) is OK, but (1,4) is not OK.

The combination of `col1` and `col2` also happens to be the primary key.

The reason to do it this way and not in separate select statements is to avoid database round-trip.

Comment: I wouldn't call it _batch select_ though, there's nothing _batch_ about it. `(col1, col2)` and `(1,3)` are called _row value constructors_. So may be rephrase the question as _Using row value constructors with the IN predicate in a SELECT statement_? I'll leave it to your judgement though.

Comment: Please show the definitions of `col1` and `col2`. Simple answer examples might be far easier if we know characteristics of the columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard SQL:

```
where (col1 = 1 and col2 = 3) or
      (col1 = 2 and col2 = 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two more options:

```
SELECT * FROM randomTable r, TABLE (VALUES (1,3),(2,4)) AS t (col1, col2) 
WHERE (r.col1, r.col2) = (t.col1, t.col2)
```

You could use the `JOIN` syntax here as well. Same with a CTE:

```
WITH t (col1, col2) AS (
  VALUES (1,3),(2,4)
)
SELECT * FROM randomTable r INNER JOIN t ON (r.col1, r.col2) = (t.col1, t.col2)
```

I believe this is all standard SQL, though not all database systems may support it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get your pairs into some type of table reference, then you can join to them.

I set up a test table like this:

```
create table qtemp.randomData
(col1   smallint
,col2   smallint
,info   varchar(20)
);

insert into randomData
values
(1, 2, 'First'),
(1, 4, 'second'),
(3, 2, 'third'),
(3, 4, 'Fourth'),
(4, 4, 'fifth');
```

Then I put my pair choices in a common table expression [CTE]

```
with p (x,y) as
(values (1,2), (3,4)
)
select d.*
  from randomData d
  join p 
    on (col1,col2)=(x,y)
;
```

Which gives

```
col1    col2    info
----    ----    --------------------
  1       2     First   
  3       4     Fourth
```

More commonly though, I would be working with a large set of keys that I would put in another table to join with.

Comment: There are some differences between DB2 for i and DB2 for z/OS.   Which part is not working?

Comment: I think it's the with statement. I get:
Error: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -104, SQLSTATE: 42601, SQLERRMC: P;DSN_INLINE_OPT_HINT
SQLState:  42601
ErrorCode: -104
Error: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -514, SQLSTATE: 26501, SQLERRMC: SQL_CURLH200C1
SQLState:  26501
ErrorCode: -514

Comment: @user3183400 As usual, please show the statement that fails. We can't guess what's wrong without seeing what you're doing. CTEs should work fine in DB2 10 for z/OS.

Comment: I am working with DB2 for i, so there are likely some differences here and there. You didnt say *which* statement.  Did you look up those SQLSTATE or SQLCODE values, or syntax diagrams?